# How to add space between menus in javafx

Tags: menu, javafx, javafx-2

I am trying to implement a menu. This is my code :

```
    Menu menuFile1 = new Menu("ADD");
    Menu menuFile2 = new Menu("EDIT");
    Menu menuFile3 = new Menu("VIEW");
    Menu menuFile4 = new Menu("HELP");
```

How can I put some space between each menu (that is between ADD,EDIT,VIEW and HELP) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Answer**

Space around menus is controlled by padding (see the [Region](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region) css guide).

For example:

```
menu.setStyle("-fx-padding: 5 10 8 10;");
```

sets the padding around the menu to 5 pixels on the top, 10 pixels on the right, 8 pixels on the bottom and 10 pixels on the left.

**Sample**

The following is a bit overcomplicated for a code sample to demonstrate this effect, but you could run it to see the effect of varying padding values.

[image: default]
[image: padded]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.StringExpression;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SpacedOut extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        MenuBar menuBar     = createMenuBar();
        VBox    controlPane = createControlPane(menuBar);

        VBox layout = new VBox(10,
                menuBar,
                controlPane
        );
        VBox.setVgrow(controlPane, Priority.ALWAYS);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout, 400, 200));
        stage.show();
    }

    private MenuBar createMenuBar() {
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        menuBar.getMenus().addAll(
            new Menu("ADD"),
            new Menu("EDIT"),
            new Menu("VIEW"),
            new Menu("HELP")
        );
        return menuBar;
    }

    private VBox createControlPane(MenuBar menuBar) {
        CheckBox useCustomPadding = new CheckBox("Use Custom Padding");
        useCustomPadding.setSelected(false);

        Slider padAmount = new Slider(0, 30, 15);
        padAmount.setShowTickMarks(true);
        padAmount.setShowTickLabels(true);
        padAmount.setMajorTickUnit(10);
        padAmount.setMaxWidth(200);
        padAmount.disableProperty().bind(
                useCustomPadding.selectedProperty().not()
        );

        VBox contentPane = new VBox(10,
                useCustomPadding,
                padAmount
        );
        contentPane.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        StringExpression paddingExpression = Bindings.concat(
                "-fx-padding: ", padAmount.valueProperty(), "px;"
        );

        menuBar.getMenus().forEach(
                menu -> menu.styleProperty().bind(
                        Bindings
                                .when(useCustomPadding.selectedProperty())
                                .then(paddingExpression)
                                .otherwise("")
                )
        );

        return contentPane;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With the `setStyle()` Method you can pass one or more css styles in one string.

Like `menuFile1.setStyle("-fx-border-color: red; -fx-effect: dropshadow( one-pass-box , red , 10,0.5,0,0 );");`

Alternatively you could put your style information inside a css file and add it to the Scene through.

```
Scene somescene = new Scene(root)
somescene.getStylesheets().add("your.css");
```

See the [css reference of Java FX 2](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) or this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm).

Comment: Thanks for that. I edited my question. Please help me one more time.